# Elasticsearch analyzers in index settings has no affect

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to set an analyzer to an index in its settings.

```js
// PUT /customers 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    },
    "dynamic": false
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": "ik_smart"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I indexed some data.

```js
// POST /customers/_doc
{
  "name": "张三",
  "title": "工程师"
}

// POST /customers/_doc
{
  "name": "李四",
  "title": "测试员"
}
```

Analyze with the `ik_smart` analyzer

```js
//GET /customers/_analyze
{
  "text": "李四工程师",
  "analyzer": "ik_smart"
}

// gets tokens ['李四', '工程师']
```

And with the default analyzer

```js
// GET /customers/_analyze
{
  "text": "李四工程师"
}

// gets tokens ['李', '四', '工', '程', '师']
```

Finally search for '李四工程师'

```js
// GET /customers/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "李四工程师",
          "operator": "or",
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "fields": [
            "name^10",
            "title^7"
          ],
          "analyzer": "ik_smart"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// gets empty hits
```

If I put the `ik_smart` analyzer into each field

```js
// PUT /customers 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ik_smart"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
         "analyzer": "ik_smart"
      }
    },
    "dynamic": false
  }
}
```

Then the request works fine.

I suspect that the first settings does not apply the analyzer to any fields within the index.

I use the `ik_smart` plugin here, which provides an `ik_smart` analyzer, because Chinese language does not have spaces to separate characters, `ik_smart` is a dictionary-based analyzer. Without the `ik_smart` analyzer, any data containing Chinese words or sentences would be indexed as single characters. So it works when I use the default analyzer in searching as well, because the phrase `李四工程师` breaks into `['李', '四', '工', '程', '师']`, and matches the indexed data. But that does not provide a very accurate relevancy.

If I use the `ik_smart` analyzer in searching, I get tokens `['李四', '工程师']`, which do not match the indexed data.

So, why isn't the `settings.analysis.analyzer` works as expected?

What is the use of this setting anyway if it does not have any affects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `ik_smart` to be the default analyzer of your index, you can set it using `default` param in the analyzer definition as explained in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/specify-analyzer.html#specify-index-time-default-analyzer) official doc.

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": { --> Note this
          "type": "simple"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that `settings.analysis.analyzer.default.type` is the analyzer option. And I just realized that `settings.analysis.analyzer` can be used to define a custom analyzer. This solved my problem. Thank you very much.